# What is the correct test to check whether a observable has changed after modifying a condition?

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I run the following 'experiment':

- take measurement x of observable
- change one parameter
- take measurement y of observable again

I do this many times and want to test whether changing the parameter has an effect on my observables. More specifically, I want to test whether changing the parameter does increase the measured value, that is, is `x < y`?

As far as I understand correctly, what I should do is a paired t-test, since I'm comparing the same measurement, before and after I change something.

However, what I'm unsure about, is what statistical test is the correct one to use?

```
[h, p_ttest1] = ttest(all_before, all_after, [] , 'left');
[h, p_ttest2] = ttest2(all_before, all_after, [], 'left');
[h, p_ttest3] = ttest(all_after - all_before, [] , 'right');
[p_signrank, h] = signrank(x, y);
```

the left-sided ttest and ttest2 yield very different p values, that's why I'm trying to understand what test is the correct one to use here.

Comment: A paired t-test will help you decide if there was a change in mean.  It will not help you decide if there was a change in variance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your data and what special information you have about it.  If there is reason to believe that there is positive correlation between the measurement before with the measurement after then a paired test is very appropriate.  Tha seems to be the case with your data.  A one-sided paired t-test would be appropriate if the measured X and Y are known or expected to be approximately normally distributed (for example you can "check" this assumption using a Shapiro-Wilk goodness of fit test) you should use the paired t test.  However if the data are very non-normal the signed rank test is appropriate and the t test is not.  Make the signed rank test one-sided.

In your code you do one-sided t tests in both directions.  it is not surprising that you get different p-values in those cases. Your alternative to x=y is according to you x < y.  So the side that tests against that alternative is the only appropriate one to use.